# Return nothing if Count SQL returns zero

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to return nothing (not zero) if a count in SQL = 0?

My code:

```
(
SELECT COUNT(Id) 
FROM t_Id pm1 
WHERE 
   pm1.id2 = M.Mid1 AND 
   pm.id3 = pm1.ProductId AND 
   pm1.Removed = 0 AND 
   pm1.StartDate >= @StartDate AND 
   pm1.StartDate < @EndDate AND 
   ms.Status = 'L'
)  AS TotalAccounts
```

If this query returns Zero, how can I return nothing (not zero), say when `COUNT(id) > 0`?

Comment: Hint: `... HAVING`.

Comment: The above looks like it's part of a subquery; so are you actually after `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

```
(
SELECT IIF(COUNT(Id) = 0, NULL, COUNT(Id))
FROM t_Id pm1 
WHERE 
   pm1.id2 = M.Mid1 AND 
   pm.id3 = pm1.ProductId AND 
   pm1.Removed = 0 AND 
   pm1.StartDate >= @StartDate AND 
   pm1.StartDate < @EndDate AND 
   ms.Status = 'L'
)  AS TotalAccounts
```

Comment: Will this work?  It's inside parentheses and the column doesn't have a name.

Comment: If it's within the `SELECT`, it'll work, @PaulAlanTaylor , as the column doesn't need an alias. But the OP hasn't given us enough detail to know where the query is being used.